# NTWaitforMultipleObjects error when freeing DLL in Delphi with TVirtualTreeView

Tags: multithreading, delphi, virtualtreeview

TVirtualTreeview is pretty much awesome, but many times when I close an window referenced by a DLL in my project that has a TVirtualTreeview in it I get the NTWaitForMultipleObjects error.

The problem is somewhere deep in TVirtualTreeview and other guys in the office have tried lots of stuff to fix it, I was just wondering if anyone else has had a similar issue in Delphi 7.

---

Or if it's fixed in 2009, because we've got that and are planning on upgrading our code (err.. beating our heads into the ground) soon.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](http://support.soft-gems.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=583&sid=9d996041a7aeb6af36e7f5c4c5553c2f) helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen that before I posted this question, but that forum thread was curiously unresolved and didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The thread Ulrich pointed to should be enough to solve this problem but I don't really think it's a bug because as I understand it you're doing it wrong:
http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/26/9804500.aspx

The solution is to clean up your form / treeview before DllMain gets called with DLL_PROCESS_DETACH.