# Delphi: TOleControl puts ActiveControl in wrong state?

Tags: delphi, focus, ole, delphi-xe6, twebbrowser

In Mike Lischke's [Virtual Treeview](http://www.delphi-gems.com/VirtualTreeview/), there was workaround code
added to fix a bug when using a **TWebBrowser** control on the same form.

The problem was that if the user tries to interact with a **TOleControl** (from which **TWebBrowser** descends), the first mouse click is eaten. They have to then click again to give the control focus. **Then** they can interact with the control.

He has comments to explain:

> Every control derived from `TOleControl` has potentially the focus problem.
>
> In order to avoid including the **OleCtrls** unit (which will, among others, include **Variants**), which would allow to test for the `TOleControl` class, the `IOleClientSite` interface is used for the test, which is supported by `TOleControl` and a good indicator.

From the full snippit:

```
procedure TBaseVirtualTree.WMKillFocus(var Msg: TWMKillFocus);
var
  Form: TCustomForm;
  Control: TWinControl;
  Pos: TSmallPoint;
  Unknown: IUnknown;
begin
  inherited;

  [snip]

  {
    Workaround for wrapped non-VCL controls (like TWebBrowser), 
    which do not use VCL mechanisms and 
    leave the ActiveControl property in the wrong state, 
    which causes trouble when the control is refocused.
  }
  Form := GetParentForm(Self);
  if Assigned(Form) and (Form.ActiveControl = Self) then
  begin
    Cardinal(Pos) := GetMessagePos;
    Control := FindVCLWindow(SmallPointToPoint(Pos));
    {
      Every control derived from TOleControl has potentially 
      the focus problem. In order to avoid including 
      the OleCtrls unit (which will, among others, include Variants),  
      which would allow to test for the TOleControl
      class, the IOleClientSite interface is used for the test, 
      which is supported by TOleControl and a good indicator.
    }
    if Assigned(Control) and Control.GetInterface(IOleClientSite, Unknown) then
      Form.ActiveControl := nil;

    // For other classes the active control should not be modified. Otherwise you need two clicks to select it.
  end;
end;
```

Problem is that the workaround is no longer working for me. And to be honest i have no idea what the problem really was, and how his solution fixed it.

Is there anyone who knows what his comments understand what he's talking about, could explain what the problem is, and how what he's doing was supposed to fix it?

> Workaround for wrapped non-VCL
> controls (like TWebBrowser), which do
> not use VCL mechanisms and leave the
> ActiveControl property in the wrong
> state, which causes trouble when the
> control is refocused. Every control
> derived from TOleControl has
> potentially the focus problem.

The code is reaching the intended

```
Form.ActiveControl := nil;
```

statement, but it just isn't doing the trick.

i'd fix it, but i have no idea how he found it, or how it can come about that **TOleControl** doesn't "*use VCL mechanisms and leaves the ActiveControl property in the wrong state*."

---

## Bonus Reading

I originally asked this question [on
`borland.public.delphi.nativeapi.win32` newsgroup in 2008](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.delphi.nativeapi.win32/AZpYwJuttIM)

[Question on Soft-Gems forum](http://support.soft-gems.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=2259)

**Bump 20110515** (12 months later)

**Bump 20150401** (7 years later): Still doesn't work in XE6

**Bump 20210309** (11 years later)

Comment: Is Virtual TreeView defunct. Last version from 14. mars 09? Probably the greatest Delphi Component ever IMHO.

Comment: It was defunct when i first asked the question. When Mike moved on to Mac and MySQL development, it was not looking good for VT. There is some sporadic support, but nothing official.

Comment: While retagging this question to use some existing tags, I found that the tvirtualtreeview tag already existed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687438/ . You would know better which is correct, so would you mind changing one of them? Thanks.

Comment: Mike himself refers to the product as Virtual Treeview, and if you search Google for virtualtreeview and tvirtualtreeview, you'll find a lot more entries for the former. So I've changed the tag of the other question from tvirtualtreeview to virtualtreeview.

Comment: VirtualTreeview's latest version 4.8.5 does not work in Delphi 2009, and there is no indication in their Forums if anyone is looking into this.

Comment: "does not work in Delphi 2009". And what am I then using at the moment? Code from the stars? 4.8.5 works. Even 4.7.0 works with Delphi 2009.

Comment: The official site and forums are dead. For something less official look here: http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic149437_virtualtreeview+wer+hat+die+weiterentwicklung+uebernommen.html (in German).

Comment: Does an update on 2009-03-16 mean that the website is dead?

http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=53&Itemid=1

Comment: I wanted to say that there is no central place for development discussion (like Mantis). Discussion takes place e.g. at Delphi-Praxis. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

I have  overcome this issue by using TEmbeddedWB (which is much better than the standard TWebBrowser) and then I had to add this OnShowUI event:

```
function THtmlFrame.webBrowserShowUI(const dwID: Cardinal;
  const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
  const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
  const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HRESULT;
begin
  try
    if WebBrowser.CanFocus then
      WebBrowser.SetFocus; // tell the VCL that the web-browser is focused
  except
    on E: EInvalidOperation do
      ; // ignore "Cannot focus inactive or invisible control"
  end;
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;
```

But if you must use TWebBrowser you need to write more code:

```
type
  IDocHostUIHandler = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{bd3f23c0-d43e-11cf-893b-00aa00bdce1a}']
    function ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPOINT;
      const CommandTarget: IUnknown; const Context: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDOCHOSTUIINFO): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
      const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
      const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function HideUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function UpdateUI: HRESULT; stdcall;
    function EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRECT; const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow; const fRameWindow: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID; const nCmdID: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetOptionKeyPath(out pchKey: POLESTR; const dw: DWORD): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget; out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POLESTR; out ppchURLOut: POLESTR): HRESULT; stdcall;
    function FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject; out ppDORet: IDataObject): HRESULT; stdcall;
  end; // IDocHostUIHandler

  ICustomDoc = interface(IUnknown)
    ['{3050f3f0-98b5-11cf-bb82-00aa00bdce0b}']
    function SetUIHandler(const pUIHandler: IDocHostUIHandler): HResult; stdcall;
  end;

  TDocHostUIHandler = class(TInterfacedObject, IDocHostUIHandler)
  private
    FWebBrowser: TWebBrowser;
  protected
    function EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject; out ppDORet: IDataObject): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget; out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HResult; stdcall;
    function GetOptionKeyPath(var pchKey: POLESTR; const dw: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function HideUI: HResult; stdcall;
    function OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRECT; const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow;
      const fFrameWindow: BOOL): HResult; stdcall;
    function ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPOINT;
      const pcmdtReserved: IInterface; const pdispReserved: IDispatch): HResult; stdcall;
    function ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject;
      const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget; const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame;
      const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HResult; stdcall;
    function TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID; const nCmdID: DWORD): HResult; stdcall;
    function TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POLESTR; var ppchURLOut: POLESTR): HResult; stdcall;
    function UpdateUI: HResult; stdcall;
  public
    constructor Create(AWebBrowser: TWebBrowser);
    property WebBrowser: TWebBrowser read FWebBrowser;
  end;


{ TDocHostUIHandler }

function TDocHostUIHandler.EnableModeless(const fEnable: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.FilterDataObject(const pDO: IDataObject; out ppDORet: IDataObject): HResult;
begin
  ppDORet := nil;
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.GetDropTarget(const pDropTarget: IDropTarget; out ppDropTarget: IDropTarget): HResult;
begin
  ppDropTarget := nil;
  Result := E_FAIL;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.GetExternal(out ppDispatch: IDispatch): HResult;
begin
  ppDispatch := nil;
  Result := E_FAIL;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.GetHostInfo(var pInfo: TDocHostUIInfo): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.GetOptionKeyPath(var pchKey: POLESTR; const dw: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_FAIL;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.HideUI: HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.OnDocWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.OnFrameWindowActivate(const fActivate: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.ResizeBorder(const prcBorder: PRECT; const pUIWindow: IOleInPlaceUIWindow; const fFrameWindow: BOOL): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.ShowContextMenu(const dwID: DWORD; const ppt: PPOINT; const pcmdtReserved: IInterface; const pdispReserved: IDispatch): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.TranslateAccelerator(const lpMsg: PMSG; const pguidCmdGroup: PGUID; const nCmdID: DWORD): HResult;
begin
  Result := S_FALSE;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.TranslateUrl(const dwTranslate: DWORD; const pchURLIn: POLESTR; var ppchURLOut: POLESTR): HResult;
begin
  Result := E_FAIL;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.UpdateUI: HResult;
begin
  Result := S_OK;
end;

function TDocHostUIHandler.ShowUI(const dwID: DWORD; const pActiveObject: IOleInPlaceActiveObject; const pCommandTarget: IOleCommandTarget;
  const pFrame: IOleInPlaceFrame; const pDoc: IOleInPlaceUIWindow): HResult;
begin
  try
    if WebBrowser.CanFocus then
      WebBrowser.SetFocus; // tell the VCL that the web-browser is focused
  except
    on E: EInvalidOperation do
      ; // ignore "Cannot focus inactive or invisible control"
  end;
  Result := S_OK;
end;



// install the DocHostUIHandler into the WebBrowser
var
  CustomDoc: ICustomDoc;
begin
  if WebBrowser1.Document.QueryInterface(ICustomDoc, CustomDoc) = S_OK then
    CustomDoc.SetUIHandler(TDocHostUIHandler.Create(WebBrowser1));
end;
```

Comment: i am using TEmbeddedWB, but the problem also happens with TWebBrowser - and i wouldn't want people going off on a tangent blaming TEmbeddedWB.  i tried adding CanFocus/SetFocus to the OnShowUI event - doesn't work. Mainly because the OnShowUI event doesn't actually get fired until i click on the web browser control.